# Code pulling extra results from array discord.py

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, discord.py

when running this code it pulls 2-3 results. Is there a better way for my if statement to verify if the content typed is in the array? could someone explain to me whats happening?

```py
def getClosing(stock):
    site = requests.get('https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}'.format(stock)).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(site,'lxml')    
    stock_data = soup.find('div', class_ = 'D(ib) Mend(20px)').text    
    return stock_data

    
@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    print('we have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    for stock in NAS_list:
        if message.content.startswith('${}'.format(stock)):
            quote = getClosing(stock)
            await message.channel.send(quote)


client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

for example if i search for $APPL i get the following

```
122.15-1.04 (-0.84%)At close:  4:04PM EST
7.25+0.36 (+5.22%)At close:  4:00PM EST
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `in` keyword

```py
>>> stock = "AAPL"
>>> stocks_list = ["AAPL", "TSLA", "DIS", "NKE", "SBUX"]
>>> stock in stocks_list
True
```

To also make it work with the prefix

```py
>>> content = "$AAPL"
>>> stocks_list = ["AAPL", "TSLA", "DIS", "NKE", "SBUX"]
>>> 
>>> stock = content[1:] # If you're using python3.9+ you can use the `str.removeprefix` method
>>> print(stock)
AAPL
>>> if stock in stocks_list:
...     # Make the request
```

Applied to your code

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("$"): # Checking if it starts with the right prefix
        stock = message.content[1:] # Removing the prefix

        if stock in NAS_list: # I'm guessing the NAS_list variable is a list of valid stocks (?)
            quote = getClosing(stock)
            await message.channel.send(quote)
```

Also you shouldn't really use the `requests` library, it's blocking, you should use [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) instead.

Comment: Hello, yes NAS_list is a list of all the stocks from the NYSE and NASDAQ. Its strange when i run your code my chatbot doesn't respond. 

I am using repl.it and the console doesn't even register anything. Do you have an idea of why this would be?

Comment: Nope never used repl.it, try running it like a normal python script in your console